# html code using a php if-statement

Tags: php, html, isset

I have the following problem:

I would like to show and hide input fields when a variable from the PHP script is set. Further it will include a second condition which also will show or hide another input field.

I would like to know if something like this is possible:

```
<?php if(isset($var) && $var =="S0"):?>
  <div>
     inputfield1        
  </div>

  <?php if(isset($var) && ($var =="S0" || $var =="S2"):?>
      <div>
         inputfield2        
      </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div>
     inputfield3        
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: yes, that doesn't work. it will error the message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in the line with the second condition

Comment: Try it yourself. Doesn't work? Debug! Still doesn't work, ask here for support with error messages.

Comment: Then check what the value of $var is before the if statement. (`echo $var;`)

Comment: `<?php if(isset($var) && ($var =="S0" || $var =="S2")):?>` note the extra `)` before the `:`

Comment: How do you set `$var?` If it is part of the URL try `$_GET['var']` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing 1 bracket in second condition

```
<?php if(isset($var) && ($var =="S0" || $var =="S2")):?>
```

Comment: hello and thanks. no this even will hide all fields. i also checked $var- i can set it through the db to s0 or s2. even when i echo $var it will be the same as expected.

Comment: @j.D., this answer is to fix the parse error.

Comment: ahh right. the parse error is gone. now i have the problem, that no inputfields will be displayed. i think the problem is the opening condition where only when $var =="S0" will display the fields. is $var =="S2" this can't be shown. thats why i was asking this question if <?php if(isset($var) && ($var =="S0" || $var =="S2")):?>
 also includes the case when $var =="S2"is set that the fields should be displayed or not?

Comment: so before people are downvoting, they better should read and understand my question.